# How to download image from URL in app + web in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Is there any package or method available to save/download image from URL in flutter for web as well app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase storage or s3-Cognito to achieve this. First, you need to upload the image to the Database using file picker or image picker and use the getDownloadUrl() method to get the imageUrl

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a package.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

TextButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          String imageUrl='https://......example';
          Uint8List response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl)).then(
          (value) => value.bodyBytes);
          
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
              content: Image.memory(response),
              );
            },
          );
        },
        child: Text(
          'Show Image from memory',
        ));
```

This code alone works without any packages. Now that you have it in memory, you can store it and do other things with it. Convert it between base64 and Unit8List.